# python is skipping over my if statement

Tags: python, binary

```
N1 = int(input("What interger do you wish to turn to binary (from 0 - 7 only!)"))
while (N1 > 7) or (N1 <0) :
    N1 = int(input("You input must be from 0 - 7 only!"))
while True:
    if N1 == 0:
        print ("0 0 0")
        break

    else:
        a = (N1 - 4)
        if a < 0:
            a = 0
        else:
            a = 1
            N1 = a

        b = (N1 - 2)
        if b < 0:
            b = 0
        else:
            b = 1
            N1 = b 

        c = (N1 - 1)
        if c < 0:
            c = 0
        else:
            c = 1

        print(a,b,c)
        break
```

## this program turns int to binary but it's skipping line 8-13 why?

Comment: you should create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example... btw while doing that you might find out why its not working http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You may find [this Wikipedia article on software flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) useful. At the least you can "manually" walk through this program (by hand) in order to deduce possible outcomes; and identify the logic error you are experiencing.

Comment: Also, please include the input you are applying, and the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this bit:

```
a = (N1 - 4)
    if a < 0:
        a = 0
    else:
        a = 1
        N1 = a
```

After the `else`, you first set the value of a to 1, and then copy that value to N1. So, your program forgot what N1 was, and the outcome for b and c will always be the same. (The same problem happens again for b and c.)

By the way, there are more efficient ways to figure out the binary representation of a number. Hint: use the `&` operator to find out whether the last bit of a number is `1`, and use the `>>` operator to shift all bits of the number to the right.

Comment: wow i feel dumb! Thanks alot! I got rid of N1 = a and added N2 = a after a = (N1 - 4 ) and then after a =1 I added N1 = N2@Han-Kwang Nienhuys

Answer (score 1):

The naive way to fix it is to remove N1 at each case and subtract different values when running if statements since N1 doesn't update while executing the second while loop. You should always avoid this happening in your codes:

```
N1 = int(input("What interger do you wish to turn to binary (from 0 - 7 only!)"))
```

while (N1 > 7) or (N1 <0) :
    N1 = int(input("You input must be from 0 - 7 only!"))
while True:
    if N1 == 0:
        print ("0 0 0")
        break

```
else:
    a = (N1 - 4)
    if a < 0:
        a = 0
    else:
        a = 1


    b = (N1 - 6)
    if b < 0:
        b = 0
    else:
        b = 1


    c = (N1 - 7)
    if c < 0:
        c = 0
    else:
        c = 1

    print(a,b,c)
    break
```

But you can do it in an iterative style:

```
    N1 = int(input("What interger do you wish to turn to binary (from 0 - 7 only!)"))
if (N1 > 7) or (N1 <0) :
    N1 = int(input("You input must be from 0 - 7 only!"))
else:
    binary = []
    if N1 == 0:
        print ("0 0 0")
    for i in range (0,3):
        if (N1 - pow(2,(2 - i))) >= 0:
            binary.append(1)
            N1 = N1 - pow(2,(2 - i))
        else:
            binary.append(0)
    print binary
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a binary built in function.

Answer (score 0):

... I've test it and it works! ( it works only when a < 0 so only with N1 < 4 because a = N1-4, 4 - 4 = 0, 0 = 0, so 0 not < 0, and the if statement doesn't work with 4, and naturally doesn't work with 5, 6, 7... too )